# Error in loading data using Dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to draw simple scatter plot using dimple.js. It works if my dataset is small . But if i take large dataset of index 15000 then it will not works, How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Posting your code is usually helpful

Answer (score 0):

The browser can handle 2k or so records when creating dimple charts, any more and the browser will crash (too complex). Aggregate your data offline or use something like http://dimplecharts.com which has an online pivot table tool that could potentially group and sum values. That tool creates a file. Then select a scatter plot layout in dimplecharts and then the shuffle button to load your pivot result into the chart, it does this automatically via the shuffle button.